# R: data.table using a for loop to wrangle multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently working in R to build a for loop which will add the year to 7 columns that contain partial dates (dd/mm). I have been attempting to run the following for-loop and have not been successful. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a sample of what my data set looks like (The actual data set includes columns HomDate - HomDate_7 but I only included the first few as I know you'll get the point...)

```
    Participant  DateVisit  HomDate  HomDate_2  HomeDate_3  year_flag
    1            2012-04-25 18/04    19/04      20/04       NA
    2            2012-01-04 28/12    29/12      30/12       1
    3            2012-01-05 31/12    01/01      01/02       1
    4            2012-06-13 06/06    07/06      08/06       NA
    5            2012-02-12 05/02    06/02      07/02       NA
```

Here's the code I've been trying to use:

```
   hom_date <- list("HomDate", "HomDate_2", "HomDate_3", "HomDate_4", "HomDate_5", "HomDate_6",         
   "HomDate_7")
   set_dates <- function(x){
   home_morbid[,x:=as.character(x)]
   home_morbid[(substr(x, 4, 5)==12) & (year_flag==1), x:=paste(x, "/2011", sep="")]
   home_morbid[(substr(x, 4, 5)==01) & (year_flag==1), x:=paste(x, "/2012", sep="")]
   home_morbid[is.na(year_flag), x:=paste(x, "/", substr(DateVisit, 1, 4), sep="")]
    }

   for(i in 1:length(hom_date)){
     x <- hom_date[i]
     home_morbid_2<-set_dates(x)
    }
```

Comment: You should use `.SD` and `.SDcols` to fully utilise `data.table`'s functionality(assuming you mean `data.table` and not a data table How would you summarise your aim in words?

Comment: @NelsonGon thanks for the tip! Do you have an example of how I can implement this in my for loop?

Comment: I am not sure if I could. Could you edit to explain what you want to do with the dates in words?

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm attempting to add the years to the end of the dates... either 2011 or 2012. This is based on the DateVisit value. In some places, the series of HomDates within the same row of DateVisit have dates that overlap 2012 and 2011.... (i.e. HomDate==31/12 and HomDate_1==01/01). In these instances, year_flag==1. I've added the workaround for these in my code. For rows where year_flag==NA, I'd simply just need to paste the year from DateVisit onto the end of the HomDate values.

Comment: Please check my answer below and let me know if it helps or help clarify where it fails

Comment: @boodaloo1Can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what happens to those with an `NA` flag. Here is an approach:

```
    to_replace<-grep("^Hom",names(df))
df[,(to_replace):=lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.na(year_flag),x,
       ifelse(substr(x, 4, 5)==12,
                               paste0(x,"/","2011"),
                                         paste0(x,"/","2012")))),
    .SDcols=HomDate:HomeDate_3][]
   Participant  DateVisit    HomDate  HomDate_2 HomeDate_3 year_flag
1:           1 2012-04-25      18/04      19/04      20/04        NA
2:           2 2012-01-04 28/12/2011 29/12/2011 30/12/2011         1
3:           3 2012-01-05 31/12/2011 01/01/2012 01/02/2012         1
4:           4 2012-06-13      06/06      07/06      08/06        NA
5:           5 2012-02-12      05/02      06/02      07/02        NA
```

To replace `NA` flagged years with the year from `DateVisit`:

```
 library(lubridate)
 to_replace<-grep("^Hom",names(df))
 df[,(to_replace):=lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.na(year_flag),
                             paste0(x,"/",year(ymd(DateVisit))),
                                            ifelse(substr(x, 4, 5)==12,
                                            paste0(x,"/","2011"),
                                                paste0(x,"/","2012")))),
   .SDcols=HomDate:HomeDate_3][]
   Participant  DateVisit    HomDate  HomDate_2 HomeDate_3 year_flag
1:           1 2012-04-25 18/04/2012 19/04/2012 20/04/2012        NA
2:           2 2012-01-04 28/12/2011 29/12/2011 30/12/2011         1
3:           3 2012-01-05 31/12/2011 01/01/2012 01/02/2012         1
4:           4 2012-06-13 06/06/2012 07/06/2012 08/06/2012        NA
5:           5 2012-02-12 05/02/2012 06/02/2012 07/02/2012        NA
```